# SQL Table Hyperlink to Edit row data using php, possible?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I need to set up an online form to edit a MySQL database using PHP.

I was hoping to set up a default column in each row of the table with a hyperlink which will take you to the editing form (web page), and in the process, pre-fill the data from the row in which you click 'edit' on.

For example the My SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    UserID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(40),
    Email varchar (50),
    key UserID (UserID),
    EditDetails VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<a href= http://webpage.with.wdit.form> Edit</a>;
    )
```

Another page will be set up to allow you to view all the details in the table.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could make it so that if you click on the 'edit' hyperlink in the last column, you would get taken to the editing web page and a php script will run to prefill the form with the details from the row you are wanting to edit?

Comment: you may need your own UI for mysql

Answer (score 0):

This is a common method and there are lots of tutorials out there on the web to help you with this.

Couple of them:

[Example one](http://www.freezecoders.com/2012/11/add-list-edit-delete-record-in-database-using-php.html)
[Example Two](http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/3064-basic-php-system-view-edit-add-delete-records-with-mysqli/)

And for inline editing, you can use this plugin:

[Datatables Editable](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html)

Comment: Thank you I will check them out